A converse to Heine's Theorem about uniformly continuous functions on the real line
Let $I$ be a non-trivial interval such that every continuous function on $I$ is uniformly continuous. Prove that $I$ is closed and bounded (that is, compact).
My solution: suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $I$ is not closed. Since $I$ is non trivial, we may say, without loss of generality, that $I = (a, b]$, for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. Define
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{x-a}\ \text{for all}\ x \in I. 
$$
Note that $f$ is continuos since it is the quotient of two continuos functions with non-vanishing denominator. Let $x_{n} = a+(1/n),\ y_{n}= a+ (1/n^{2})$ for every $n\geq 1$. Then we get two sequences of points in $I$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n}-y_{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} a+\frac{1}{n}-a-\frac{1}{n^{2}} = 0,$$
but
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_{n})-f(y_{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{n}-a}-\frac{1}{a+\frac{1}{n^{2}}-a} = \lim_{n\to\infty}n-n^{2}.
$$
So the sequence $(f(x_{n})-f(y_{n}))$ does not converge to zero (it is divergent). This means that $f$ fails to be uniformly continuous, a contradiction.
Is this correct? Should I also do the case wehere $I$ is not bounded? And, is a direct proof also viable?

Good job. If $I $ is unbounded show that $f(x)=x^{2}$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous.

And how about a direct proof? I’ve thought about using the sequential characterization of compact sets.

The fact that $I$ is an interval is important. Every function from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous, so it is not enough to just know that there is a sequence with no convergent subsequence.
